# How INTER_LINEAR interpolation in OpenCV resize() work?

Tags: opencv, resize, interpolation

I am figuring out how OpenCV resize() function calculates linear interpolation when we set `fx=2` and `fy=1`. I have written the following minimum working example,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

pattern_img = np.zeros((6, 6), np.uint8)
pattern_img[:, 0::2] = 255
patteen_img_x2 = cv2.resize(pattern_img, None, fx=2, fy=1, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

if we look at the first row of `pattern_img` and `pattern_img_x2`, we will have,

```
pattern_img[0, :]
> array([255,   0, 255,   0, 255,   0], dtype=uint8)
pattern_img_x2[0, :]
> array([[255, 191,  64,  64, 191, 191,  64,  64, 191, 191,  64,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

I cannot figure out how numbers 191 and 64 are calculated. I know that it implements `bilinear` algorithm, but in this case we have set `fy=1`, so it shall be a simple linear interpolation along x-axis. But I cannot figure out how `resize()` calculate those interpolated numbers. Could anybody help me to understand the algorithm behind?

Comment: Hi Rasoul, this might be too detailed, but here is the source code for the OpenCV resize: 
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp

Answer (score 7):

This has to do with pixel "grids".

Is 0,0 the *center* of the first pixel, or the *top left corner* of it? Where are the corners of a pixel? A common question in computer graphics.

Interpolation adds another complication. Does a pixel define its whole square area? Then you get nearest neighbor interpolation. Or does it merely define the center point? Then, anything in between is *undefined*, technically, and interpolation gets to decide how to fill the space.

In OpenCV generally, pixel *centers* are at *integer* coordinates. That means the first pixel's top left *corner* sits at (-0.5, -0.5), so that's where the *picture*'s top left corner starts.

Now, if you were to sample with fx=1, i.e. an identity transformation, you'd start at -0.5, which should be the left edge of a pixel, and the output pixel has a width of 1, so the first output pixel spans -0.5 to +0.5, and its *center is at 0.0*.

Since you want fx=2, your output pixels are 0.5 wide. You still start at -0.5, and your output pixels span... -0.5 to 0.0, 0.0 to +0.5, 0.5 to 1.0, 1.0 to 1.5...

And their centers sit at -0.25, +0.25, +0.75, +1.25, ...

And **that** is how you get those 1/4 and 3/4 values. 64 is one quarter of 255, 191 is three quarters of 255. And that's also why the first output pixel is 255. It sits to the left of the first input pixel, so that is its only support and determines 100% of its value.

You could "index-shift" this all so it is a little easier to visualize. Then the picture's top left pixel's top left corner is at (0,0), and the pixel extends to (1,1), with the center at (0.5,0.5). The output pixel grid lies accordingly, top left pixel going from 0 to 0.5 with center at 0.25, its neighbor to the right spanning 0.5 to 1.0, center at 0.75, and so on.

If you want to have full control over this madness, construct your own affine transformation (I'd recommend working with 3x3 matrices, easy to compose/matrix-multiply) and then use `warpAffine`. It'll take integer coordinates for the output, transform them using your matrix (it implicitly inverts it), and looks the resulting coordinates up in the source image, including interpolation in the source image space.

[image: pixel grid: input] [image: pixel grid: input and output]

Made a little graphic here (click for full size). Black squares are input pixels, black dots their centers. Red squares and dots are the output pixels and their centers. You see, if you sample at the red dot positions, you'll sit at one or three quarters between input pixel centers.